# Observable.FromEvent, cannot get signatures right

Tags: system.reactive

I'm trying to create an IObservable from the following event:

```
public delegate bool Handle<in T>(T obj, Foo foo);

 event Handle<Bar> Finance;
```

Any suggestions on how to properly create the observable?

Note, neither Foo nor Bar is based on EventArgs

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for Handle<Bar>. Hilarious

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
public class Test
{
    public delegate void Handle<in T>(T obj, Foo foo);

    public event Handle<Bar> Finance;
}

public static class TestEx
{
    static IObservable<Tuple<Bar, Foo>> WhenFinanceChanged(this Test t)
    {
        return Observable.Create<Tuple<Bar, Foo>>(observer =>
        {
            Test.Handle<Bar> handler = (obj, foo) => observer.OnNext(Tuple.Create<Bar, Foo>(obj, foo));
            t.Finance += handler;
            return Disposable.Create(() => t.Finance -= handler);
        });
    }
}
```